# Simplexml not displaying info

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I have made a search html page using IMDBAPI to create an xml file for that item I search. Then I have a php file that will parse through that file and only pull the data I want from the xml file to display. Everything seems to be working as I am getting a blank white page. The issue is that nothing is displaying.

Part of the XML

```
<IMDBDocumentList>
<item>
<rating>8.7</rating>
<rating_count>10301</rating_count>
<year>1999</year>
<genres>
<item>Animation</item>
<item>Action</item>
<item>Adventure</item>
<item>Comedy</item>
<item>Drama</item>
<item>Fantasy</item>
<item>Romance</item>
</genres>
<rated>PG</rated>
<title>Wan pÃ®su: One Piece</title>
<imdb_url>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0388629/</imdb_url>
<directors>
<item>KÃ´nosuke Uda</item>
</directors>
<actors>
<item>Mayumi Tanaka</item>
<item>Kazuya Nakai</item>
<item>Akemi Okamura</item>
<item>Kappei Yamaguchi</item>
<item>Mahito Ã”ba</item>
<item>Hiroaki Hirata</item>
<item>Colleen Clinkenbeard</item>
<item>Ikue Ã”tani</item>
<item>Chikao Ã”tsuka</item>
<item>Yuriko Yamaguchi</item>
<item>Luci Christian</item>
<item>Christopher Sabat</item>
<item>Sonny Strait</item>
<item>Kazuki Yao</item>
</actors>
```

PHP Parse

```
$lib  = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$xml = $lib->IMDBDocumentList->item;
$rating = $xml->rating;
$year = $xml->year;
print $rating;
print $year;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IMDBDocumentList` is your *root* node, so you don't need to address it:

```
$xml = $lib->item;
```